# Include split token in returned values when splitting

Tags: regex, postgresql

I would like to include the token used to split text in the regex_split_to_table function.

so

```
select regex_split_to_table('mr smith mrs smith','mr|mrs');
```

returns:

```
mr smith
mrs smith
```

currently `mr` and `mrs` are stripped out.
How do I do this?

Cheers
O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookeahead:

```
# select regexp_split_to_table('mr smith mrs smith','(?=mrs|mr)');
 regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
 mr smith 
 mrs smith
(2 rows)
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/6i61lX/1)